# How to calculate the sum for all files in a directory when to iterate them?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

All files in directory `survey` contain same structure.
Data in `x1.xls`:
[image]
Data in `x2.xls`:
[image]
I want to get sum of `b` column and `c` column for both `x1.xls` and `x2.xsl`.
Result for `x1.xls`.
[image]

Same sum for `x2.xls`.
I can do with following steps:
1.Open vb editor in `x1.xls`
2.Edit the below `sub` and bind `ctrl+z` with the `sub sum`.

```
Sub Sum()
    Dim BottomOfTable As Long
    BottomOfTable = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(BottomOfTable + 1, "A").Value = "score"
    Range("B" & BottomOfTable + 1).Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=round(SUM(R[-" & BottomOfTable - 1 & "]C:R[-1]C)" & ",2)"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("b" & BottomOfTable + 1 & ":" & "c" & BottomOfTable + 1), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("b" & BottomOfTable + 1 & ":" & "c" & BottomOfTable + 1).Select    
End Sub
```

Different files contain different rows,so use `Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` to get dynamic rows for different files.

3.Press `ctrl+z` in `x1.xls`.
4.Open `x2.xls` and press `ctrl+z`.

Now i want to automate the process with vba.

Here is my try:

```
Sub ListDir()
Dim FileName As String
Dim myPath as string
myPath="d:\survey\"
FileName = Dir(myPath, vbNormal)
Do While FileName <> ""
    targetFile =  myPath & FileName
    sumColumns(targetFile)
    FileName = Dir()
Loop
End Sub


Function sumColumns(targetFile)    
    Dim BottomOfTable As Long, AK As Workbook
    Set AK = Workbooks.Open(targetFile)
    BottomOfTable = AK.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(BottomOfTable + 1, "A").Value = "score"
    Range("B" & BottomOfTable + 1).Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=round(SUM(R[-" & BottomOfTable - 1 & "]C:R[-1]C)" & ",2)"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("b" & BottomOfTable + 1 & ":" & "c" & BottomOfTable + 1), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("b" & BottomOfTable + 1 & ":" & "c" & BottomOfTable + 1).Select  
    AK.Close  
End Function
```

When i execute the `sub ListDir()` `x1.xsl` in vba editor ,an error occur:

[image]

and maybe there are some other bugs in `sumColumns` function,how to fix to get what i expect result sum for all files in directory `survey`?

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot do that without (programmatically) opening each of them (in Execel), do the data processing and closing them (with Saving = True).

Comment: Is the file containing your macro in the same folder?

Comment: It is better to consider two scenario: the file containing  macro in the same folder;and the  file containing  macro not in the same folder,in other folder.

Comment: If the former you need to build in a check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should be in a different file than the ones you're trying to modify.

You may run it using F8 key so you say what changes between your code and mine.

Read the comments and adjust it to fit your needs.

```
' This option should go at the top of all modules when you write VBA code. So it warns you when you're not defining your variables
Option Explicit

Public Sub ListDir()
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim targetFilePath As String

    myPath = "d:\survey\"
    fileName = Dir(myPath, vbNormal)

    ' If something goes wrong, don't let the screen updating option off
    On Error GoTo CleanError

    ' Turn off screen updating so there is no flickering when opening and closing files
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Do While fileName <> ""
        targetFilePath = myPath & fileName
        sumColumns targetFilePath
        fileName = Dir()
    Loop

CleanExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

CleanError:
    MsgBox "Something went wrong..."
    GoTo CleanExit
End Sub

Private Function sumColumns(targetFilePath)
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    ' Open and set a reference to workbook
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(targetFilePath)

    ' Set a reference to the first = 1 worksheet in file (beware that this may not always be the first visible sheet)
    Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    ' Get the row number of the last non empty cell in column A (here you should always be careful for what you're defining as non empty)
    lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Set the label in cell
    targetSheet.Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Value = "score"

    ' Set the formula to sum the values in each column
    targetSheet.Range("B" & lastRow + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=round(SUM(R[-" & lastRow - 1 & "]C:R[-1]C)" & ",2)"
    targetSheet.Range("C" & lastRow + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=round(SUM(R[-" & lastRow - 1 & "]C:R[-1]C)" & ",2)"

    ' Close saving changes
    targetWorkbook.Close True
End Function
```

Please remember to mark the answer if it helps.