# Copy sum of cells from different folders into a summary sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops

newbie here. Been trying for a whole day to do the following

1. I have about 200 differently named folders, each containing a .csv named "Bill"
2. For each .csv file, I need to do a COUNTA on column B, and SUM of column C (all files have same column structure)
3. I would like to summarise these data from individual "Bill" .scv into ONE new Excel, by "Folder Name", "Count B", "Sum C"

[Excerpt of Bill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ9NY.png)
[Summary Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPx37.png)

I've been googling around and found some helpful links but I'm unable to fully modify it to what I want ... Tried to cut and paste the result of this code and tried to pull the folder names separately but failed...
[How to calculate the sum for all files in a directory when to iterate them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59626886/how-to-calculate-the-sum-for-all-files-in-a-directory-when-to-iterate-them)

This one worked well but because the files are .CSV so renaming it automatically renamed the sheets as well...https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/extract-data-from-multiple-files-in-same-folder.937866/

Tried to get the folder names separately but couldn't merry the codes either: https://trumpexcel.com/list-of-file-names-from-a-folder-in-excel/

Appreciate if someone can help and provide some advice... thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this ok ?
(you'll need to add Microsoft Scripting Runtime Type Library
and you'll have to place this in your root folder)

```
' Variables
Dim oFso As FileSystemObject
Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oStartFolder As Folder
Dim oFolder As Folder
Dim oFile As File
Dim oWb As Workbook
Dim countA As Integer
Dim sum As Long
Dim iRow As Integer

' Init
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells.ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Folder"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value = "CountA"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 3).Value = "Sum"
iRow = 2

' Folders
Set oStartFolder = oFso.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path)
For Each oFolder In oStartFolder.SubFolders
    ' Files
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        If oFile.Name = "bill.csv" Then
            ' Open and read
            Set oWb = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=oFile.Path, local:=True)
            countA = WorksheetFunction.count(oWb.Worksheets(1).Columns(2))
            sum = WorksheetFunction.sum(oWb.Worksheets(1).Columns(3))
            oWb.Close
            ' Write
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(iRow, 1).Value = oFolder.Name
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(iRow, 2).Value = countA
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(iRow, 3).Value = sum
            iRow = iRow + 1
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: IT WORKS! I just had to modify it slightly for what i want. I've accepted your answer, let me know how can I thank you more :) :)